# Regarding JDBC connection in server

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

Hello I got stuck in below scenarios.
I have a method(Insert_values) in my java program that will get database connection & store the value in Database connection.
Scenario 1 : If i ran the method by creating main function in that class (as a java application) no error its connected with database & store the value in DB 
Scenario 2: If i ran the same in server its given **No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle** while calling that particular method(Insert_values).

Server Name -Tomcat8.0

API - Ojdbc14

Can any one give me solution for this scenario.

Comment: could you share some code to support your use cases ?

Comment: @Ravi Why? It's a simple CLASSPATH problem. No code required to see that.

Comment: @EJP isn't a good practice to ask code ?

Comment: @Ravi Certainly, when required to identify the problem. Some questions don't require it. This is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Oracle JDBC driver `.jar` file in the library path of your server, or if you're writing a web application (that's not clear from your question) include it in the `.war` file that you're building.

Comment: *that's not clear from your question* Then, you should have waited

Comment: And does that invalidate the answer, you think?

Comment: do you have complete understanding of what has happened in case 1 and case 2 ? If yes, then I don't have issue. If no, then your answer is completely on assumption

Comment: As a matter of fact it *is* perfectly clear from the question. The OP mentioned Tomcat, so he can can only be writing a webapp. @Ravi

Comment: True, I overlooked that. Still, you can still decide to put the Oracle driver into Tomcat's library directory. It'll save you a bit of memory and since JDBC is a tun-time dependency, it doesn't matter too much where you put it.